# WSO2 ESB save proxys services in database server

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Good Morning/afternoon,

how i configure ESB to save my proxy services in database server (Mysql) ?
I alter the registry.xml file in repository/conf and nothing, the services dont persist in database, only creates the tables.

Can help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently no option to save proxy configurations in the registry..But you can save other synapse artifacts in registry(eg: sequence,endpoints..) for that, you should use the option "save in registry" and select where you want to save them.